# Can't access Json value

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to access the json object passed into the `loggedIn` function.

`{"name":"craig lafferty","ID":"1"}` is output to the console but the result of `console.log(data["name"]);` is undefined. What am I missing here?

```
function loggedIn(data)
{
    console.log(data);
    console.log(data["name"]);
    $("#usernameDisplay").css({"z-index":"5"});
    $("#searchResultsContainer").css({"z-index":"3"});
    $("#usernameDisplay").text(data["name"]);
    $("#loginAddUserBack,#loginFacebook,#loginGoogle").animate({opacity: "0"}).delay(2, function(){$(this).css({"display": "none","z-index":"0"});});
    $("#menuIndic").css({"opacity":"0.3","z-index":"5"});
    $("#intro").animate({opacity: "0"}).delay(2, function(){$(this).css("display", "none");});
    $("#mainNotificationTable,#searchResultsContainer,#searchMainContainer").css("visibility", "visible");
    $("#searchTypes").css({"visibility": "visible", "z-index":"5"});
    id = data["ID"];
    //getUserInfo(username);
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your json is a string, not an actual object. Turn it into an object using `data = JSON.parse(data)` then it will work.

```
data = JSON.parse(data);
console.log(data["name"]);
```

Also note that you could just do `data.name` which is generally considered a little nicer unless you need something that bracket syntax offers (like a property name with a bad character or access property with a variable).

Comment: What's the difference between the string and the object? Also, I tried data.name and it was undefined.

Comment: Nevermind, I got it. I guess I was under the impression that the string with the bracket notation was parsed as an object from the literal string values.

Comment: @m59, you may want to mention jQuery.parseJSON - i was not aware that it is a standard feature in js 1.7.